# Is there a build-in way to dig through hashes and arrays with exception?

Tags: ruby

Ruby 2.3.0 introduced `#dig`. I'm looking for a method with similar functionality, but instead of using the `#[]` method to retrieve the value (behind the screens) it should use `#fetch`. Resulting in an exception raised when the key/index is missing.

I already have an solution for my issue using simple monkey patching.

```
module DigWithException
  def dig_e(key, *others)
    value = fetch(key)
    return value if others.empty?

    if value.respond_to?(__method__, true)
      value.__send__(__method__, *others)
    else
      raise TypeError, "#{value.class} does not have ##{__method__} method"
    end
  end
end

Array.include(DigWithException)
Hash.include(DigWithException)
```

However, this seems like such an obvious thing to be included in the Ruby core or std-lib that I was wondering if I was missing something. Is this the case?

Comment: I'm also not entirely satisfied with the method name `#dig_e`. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This code would raise weird exceptions on existing keys returning non-enumerables `{foo: {bar: 42}}.dig_e(:foo, :bar, :baz)`.

Comment: Can the method be named with a Canadian accent btw? Like `dig_eh`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin The behaviour is not much different from the original `#dig` method. Which raises a *TypeError* instead of a *NoMethodError*, but you got a point, I'll update the question. `{foo: {bar: 42}}.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz) #=> TypeError: Integer does not have #dig method`

Comment: For those interested, I've created a [feature proposition](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15563).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no equivalent like what you want in the stdlib. Most people with that need would just use chained `#[]` access.

Given:

```
foo = {bar: {baz: {bang: 1}}}
```

Subscript:

```
foo[:bar][:baz][:bin]
```

which will result in a `NoMethodError` if a key is missing (since #[] returns nil for a missing key, which you can't further subscript).

Or if you want a KeyError:

```
[:bar, :baz, :bin].reduce(foo, :fetch)
```

`#dig` is primarily a concession to the fact that we want to sometimes traverse a deeply-nested hash which may be missing intermediate keys, without having to check each access for validity.

Comment: I’d use `reduce` alias here because it seems to be more semantically correct.